# Unable to import .py file in Pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I want to Automate Web App testing using Selenium and PyTest and I am new to both. So here is the structure of my project folder:

Parent Folder
Locator.py

Section 1(Folder) -> test_sectionone.py

Locator.py contains all my Xpaths. Now when I try to import Locator.py by typing import Locator and then fetching the xpath using Locator.xpathElement1 in the test_sectionone.py, pytest fails with the following error:

*Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_mailboxProvisioning.py:5: in 
    import Locator
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Locator'*

Is there something I am missing? Is there a naming convention because of which I am facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Convert Parentfolder into a python package by including an empty file `__init__.py`
Convert sub folder "Section1" into a python package by including an empty file `__init__.py`

In test_sectionone.py now either import ParentFolder.Locator (using absolute path) or from ..Locator import function using relative path.
Both should work.